# Combining multiple groups in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a dataframe like this:

| category | year | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2022 | 5 |
| apple | 2021 | 8 |
| banana | 2022 | 1 |
| cold | 2022 | 9 |
| cold | 2021 | 2 |
| warm | 2022 | 1 |
| warm | 2021 | 3 |

I need to group the rows based on a pre-set list of groupings ('fruit', 'temperature') and then aggregate by year. The final DF would look like this:

| category | year | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fruit | 2022 | 6 |
| fruit | 2021 | 8 |
| temp | 2022 | 10 |
| temp | 2021 | 5 |

The Category values are strings. I'm looking for any solution to make this work. The actual dataframe is quite a bit longer, so I'm hoping to use something like a dict with the groupings to aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

I would [`map_dict`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.dataframe.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) the `category` column to standardize that to fruit/temperature, then a `groupby`:

```py
md = {"apple": "fruit", "banana": "fruit", "cold": "temp", "warm": "temp"}

df.with_columns(pl.col("category").map_dict(md)).groupby("category", "year").sum()
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────────┬──────┬───────┐
│ category ┆ year ┆ count │
│ ---      ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ str      ┆ i64  ┆ i64   │
╞══════════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ fruit    ┆ 2022 ┆ 6     │
│ temp     ┆ 2022 ┆ 10    │
│ fruit    ┆ 2021 ┆ 8     │
│ temp     ┆ 2021 ┆ 5     │
└──────────┴──────┴───────┘
```

You could also do a when/then chain to standardize the `category` column, but in more complicated examples `map_dict` will be more concise code.